# How to draw what is inside a contour in an image but leave everything else blank?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a colour image of type `Image<Hsv, Byte>`, and another image of type `Image<Gray, Byte>` of the same size that is all black with some all-white shapes. From the black and white image, I found the contours of the shapes using `findContours()`. What I want is to create a new image or modify the original colour image I have to show only what corresponds to inside the contours, with everything else being transparent, without having to check pixel by pixel values of the two images (did this, it takes too long). Any possible way to do this?

For example, I have the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCHE9.png), the [black and white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0LPT.png), and the [final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN6lS.png) I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely new to emgucv, so, I'm not saying this is the best approach; but it seems to work.

1. Create a new draw surface
2. Draw the original image
3. Change the white pixels in the mask image to transparent pixels
4. Draw the transparent mask on top of the original image

The result image looks like your desired outcome.

```
void Main()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
        "images");

    var original = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(Path.Combine(path, "vz7Oo1W.png"));
    var mask = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(Path.Combine(path, "vIQUvUU.png"));

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.DrawImage(original.Bitmap, 0, 0);
        g.DrawImage(MakeTransparent(mask.Bitmap), 0, 0);
    }
    bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(path, "new.png"));
}

public static Bitmap MakeTransparent(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);

    var tolerance = 10;

    for (int i = b.Size.Width - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = b.Size.Height - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            var col = b.GetPixel(i, j);
            col.Dump();

            if (255 - col.R < tolerance &&
                255 - col.G < tolerance &&
                255 - col.B < tolerance)
            {
                b.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }

    return b;
}
```